# CreateMultipartUpload operation - AWS policy items needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm doing multipart upload via aws cli console but getting this error;

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

Below is my policy, am I missing something in there?

Thanks.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:CreateMultipartUpload",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you give the full command you use to upload to s3 ?

Answer (score 23):

The  "s3:PutObject" handles the CreateMultipartUpload operation so I guess there is nothing like  "s3:CreateMultipartUpload".

The thing you have to change in your s3 bucket ARN is like
add also "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"

Final policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                         "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                         "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
                        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are using the `"Resource"` key twice in your last block. last two lines. Not sure which one it's supposed to be.

Comment: You need both. One is for the bucket it's self, one is for objects in the buck (ending /*). Resource shout be an array [] with both in.

Comment: use array of resources like `"Resource":["arn1","arn2"]`

Answer (score 2):

If it's cross accounts access, check it is not related to ACL headers as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34055538/1736679 (more info in this issue thread: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1674)

Also double check the environment  / user from which you are running to see if there are no overriding Keys (AWS_ACCESS_KEY, etc) in /etc/environment or ~/.aws/credentials