# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I'm having the error mentioned in the title when trying to upload a large file (15gb) to my s3 bucket from a Sagemaker notebook instance.

I know that there are some similar questions here that i have already visited. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541933/accessdenied-when-calling-the-createmultipartupload-operation-in-django-using-dj), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630635/createmultipartupload-operation-aws-policy-items-needed), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272286/getting-access-denied-when-calling-the-putobject-operation-with-bucket-level-per) question, but after following the steps mentioned, and applying the policies described in these questions i still have the same error.

I have also come to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-error-kms/#:%7E:text=%22An%20error%20occurred%20(AccessDenied)%20when%20calling%20the%20CreateMultipartUpload%20operation,GenerateDataKey%20and%20kms%3ADecrypt%20actions.) documentation page eventually. The problem is that when i go into my users page in the IAM section, i see no users. I can see some roles but no users and i don't know which role should i edit following the steps mentioned in the documentation page. Also, my bucket DON'T have encryption enabled so i'm not really sure that the steps in the documentation page will fix the error for me.

This is the policy in currently using for my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bauer-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bauer-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm totally lost with this, i need to upload that file to my bucket. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any solution for it? I am getting the same issue

Comment: Hi, the only solution i found (and is not a pretty one), was to remove all the access restrictions temporarily to my s3 bucket, so it was publicly accessible. I didn't find the proper solution for this, but that workaround did it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access is dictated by the execution role that is attached to the SageMaker notebook. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html goes through how add additional s3 permissions to a SageMaker execution role.