# Getting `AccessDenied` when calling any operation in AWS bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a private s3 Bucket that I've selected to `Block *all* public access` on in settings.
when I try to collect static I get an access denied error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Also, when trying to access the static files (i.e. js & css) that I've manually uploaded I get `403` code

I've made a bucket policy based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45733919/13487763):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy16144340382381",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt16144340315031",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::634515378440:user/myapp-user"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1614408230409",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::634515378440:user/myapp-user"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I added the IAM user to a group with this permission policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, here is the code in `settings.py` code that I've used to configure the app

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'storages',
    ...
]
# S3 BUCKETS CONFIG
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = True
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.storages.MediaStorage'
```

Here is `storages.py`

```py
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
import os

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = True
    bucket_name = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
```

I've even tried making new users and buckets and adding them to the policy in case the credentials were wrong, but still no result. Is there a way I can verify that the connection is being made successfully and perhaps list the permissions the user has through the boto3 client?

UPDATE:

I configured my AWS CLI profile using `myapp-user`'s credentials, and it lets me list the buckets `aws s3 ls --profile myapp-user`, I was also able to run the `aws s3 cp` command to copy files between my local pc and the bucket just fine.
So I know the credentials are fine; but at this point, I don't know what else I could do. I have made sure that the credentials I used in the AWS CLI config were identical to the ones in my env variables, but I still get the `AccessDenied` error.

Comment: You don't typically add IAM users to an S3 bucket policy. You simply give the IAM users the necessary S3 permissions via IAM policy (or IAM group membership). I'd print the access key and secret key passed to storages and ensure that they're correct - test them with the awscli (can you access the bucket with these creds?)

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the comment, when I try to remove the user from the bucket policy, I get this error: `Missing required field Principal`.
I also tried using the AWS CLI verify and it shows the credentials were correct (see update above).

Comment: S3 bucket policies, when present, need a principal. I’m saying that you would ordinarily give myapp-user S3 permissions through an IAM policy, not an S3 bucket policy. And you would delete the bucket policy entirely.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean; I just gave it a try, but I still get AccessDenied.

Comment: Which operation fails with AccessDenied? And why do you have AWS_DEFAULT_ACL set to public-read for a bucket that you’ve said has Block Public Access?

Comment: I had it set to `public-read` because I was getting a `403` when accessing the files from my page. Setting it to `None` fixed the `collecstatic` issue (and I am able to read/write programmatically). But how would I let my site have read access to the css/js files (as they currently `403`), do I need a CORS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jarmod pointed out in the comments, the reason I was getting `access denied` was because I had the `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'`, which clashed with the access settings of the bucket.
I was able to resolve it by having `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None` instead which simply inherits the bucket's access settings.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue with adding this to the bucket policy/permissions:

```
{ 
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
    ]
   }
 ]
}
```