# Codename one upload image to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, upload, codenameone

I am trying to upload an image to my s3 bucket in my codenameone project as per the thread below,

[Codename one upload image to S3 bucket permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803538/codename-one-upload-image-to-s3-bucket-permission)

But unable to do so. Getting connection error code 301 and java.lang.NullPointerException ...

To make sure my s3 bucket configurations are correct, I have successfully uploaded an image using Postman app and Javascript sdk.

I would like to understand does the above example require any additional credentials info like AccessKey, SecretKey and AWS Region? If so please guide on the same.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Below is my code.

try {

```
        String strImage = Capture.capturePhoto(300, -1);             
        String s3Bucket = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/";
        String fileName = "testimg1.jpg";
        
        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
        request.setUrl(s3Bucket);            
        request.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        request.addArgumentNoEncoding("key", fileName);            
        request.addArgument("acl", "bucket-owner-full-control");
        request.addData("file", strImage, "image/jpeg");            
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);
                 
        int http_code = request.getResponseCode();
        
        Dialog.show("Ok", String.valueOf( http_code) , "Ok", null);      
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        
        String err = ex.toString();
        Dialog.show("Err", err, "Ok", null);
    }
```

Netbeans console is showing below error.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperationComplete(ConnectionRequest.java:935)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.runCurrentRequest(NetworkManager.java:314)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:390)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[Network Thread] 0:0:6,656 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:445)
at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:668)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:149)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:135)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:170)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:124)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readInputStream(Util.java:303)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.readResponse(ConnectionRequest.java:1543)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperationComplete(ConnectionRequest.java:1003)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.runCurrentRequest(NetworkManager.java:314)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:390)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Comment: That's odd. Based on [the code](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.java#L935), it seems that you got a 301 or 302 redirect with no location header set. In postman do you get a redirect and if so which server response code and what headers?

Comment: In postman I don't get any redirect error.

Comment: The below is my curl request from postman. Where I set the Auth >> Type : AWS Signature. And provide the info of Accesskey, Secretkey, region , service etc. 
curl --location --request PUT 'https ://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test1.jpg' \ 
--header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \ 
--header 'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: xxxxxx' \ 
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20231006T041844Z' \ 
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx/20231006/ap-xx-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, 
Signature=xxxxx' \ 
--data '@/C:/Temp/TempImg.jpg'

Comment: In the curl code you have `'https ://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test1.jpg` yet here you have `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/`. So the curl code wouldn't be identical to postman.

Comment: Can you please help how to resolve my codename one issue? I am not able to figure out what's going wrong in my codename one code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Shai's suggestion I have made my bucket publicly accessible then the above code started working from codename one.

Made 2 changes in the code,

The url is now "https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/";

And used "PUT" method of request object.

Thank you Shai for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting this error but I can write code that should be similar to the curl command that you have. I haven't tried this so you might need to tune it a bit.

For reference this is the curl statement:

```bash
curl --location --request PUT 'https ://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test1.jpg' \ --header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \ --header 'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: xxxxxx' \ --header 'X-Amz-Date: 20231006T041844Z' \ --header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx/20231006/ap-xx-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxx' \ --data '@/C:/Temp/TempImg.jpg'
```

This should be the equivalent Codename One code:

```
Response<String> result = Rest.put("https ://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test1.jpg")
   .contentType("image/jpeg")
   .header("X-Amz-Content-Sha256", "xxxxxx")
   .header("X-Amz-Date", "20231006T041844Z")
   .header("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx/20231006/ap-xx-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxx")
   .body(new Data.ByteData(contentOfFile)).getAsString();
```

Comment: Hello Shai, am I missing any configuration? Could you please suggest me if I have to do any settings at ASW S3 or codename one project end? We are using codenameone for android mobile app since a long. Now we are in a situation where we have to fulfill our customer requirement of uploading an image (strictly camera click) from mobile app to s3 bucket. Please please do suggest something. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the curl command works as a standalone then this API call should be the general equivalent of that and require no additional configuration. If there's a problem you can use the network monitor tool and see the errors you're getting from AWS. This can be used to debug such a problem.

Comment: Postman's curl command doesn't work stand alone though. I am looking for codename one solution as mentioned in my problem statement. I am curious how the other codename one users are doing it. I have mentioned postman example just to ensure that my bucket is created successfully and I am able to upload the files from postman as well as javascript sdk. I am more interested in  codename one solution. i.e. String s3Bucket = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/";
String fileName = "testimg1.jpg";        
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
request.setUrl(s3Bucket);

Comment: OK. So if it doesn't work standalone this might be a problem with the S3 configuration. That other solution works by having a world writable bucket, not an ideal solution. The main problem is authentication/authorization in S3. If you create a writable bucket that original code should work just fine.

Comment: Ok. Will check. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Shai. It works when I make mybucket full publicly accessible. But as you said this is not advisable. Can you please suggest some other way where I can provide my bucket credentials like AccessKey and SecretKey?

Comment: This isn't something I tried personally so I can't really tell. If you look at the code I provided above it requires the values that are clearly generated from the authorization process. I'm not sure how those are generated for AWS but they probably can be generated here too.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for all the assistance. Now at least I have one of the solutions ready.